# Permission error, having trouble loading parquet files from AWS S3 to SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, azure, amazon-s3, parquet

Basically every time I try to connect to AWS bucket to grab a parquet file in SQL Server 2022, I am getting a permission error

> Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 's3_dc', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Code:

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;  
RECONFIGURE;

exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL s3_dc
WITH IDENTITY = 'IDENTITY',
     SECRET = 'SECRET' ;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE s3_ds 
    WITH (LOCATION = 's3://s3.amazonaws.com',    
          CREDENTIAL = s3_dc ); 
GO

SELECT *  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'buckett/haz/data/data.parquet',
                FORMAT = 'PARQUET', 
                data_source = 's3_ds') AS [cc];
```

That's the error message:

> Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 's3_dc', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I tried disabling firewall, and tried logging in as SQL Server user and as a windows user, still getting same error.

Comment: does it work to add a GO before CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE s3_ds ?

Comment: nope, it didn't make any deference

Comment: does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554261/cannot-find-the-credential-db-scoped-creds-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you

Comment: Have you read the `CREATE EXTERNAL DATASOURCE` documentation? In discussing the `CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL` it says, _Must be a database scoped credential, where the `IDENTITY` is hard-coded to `IDENTITY = 'S3 Access Key'` and the `SECRET` argument is in the format `= '<AccessKeyID>:<SecretKeyID>'`_

Comment: Thank you so much!. If you can change your reply as a post I'll mark it as a solution because it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

With below command check if your scoped credentials are exist or not

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_credentials;
```

If they exist still facing the issue you need to give permission to access the DATABASE SCOPED to your user, use below command to grant permisson:

```sql
GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL::[{credential_name}] TO [{user}];
```

For more information refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

**Updated answer to help other community members as @AlwaysLearning said**

while creating credentials Identity should be hardcoded as `IDENTITY = 'S3 Access Key'`
`SECRET` value also should be in proper format of `<access_key_id>:<secret_key_id>`

For more information refer this [Create external data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated#d-create-external-data-source-to-query-a-parquet-file-in-s3-compatible-object-storage-via-polybase) documnet